# Android MaterialButton padding between drawableLeft icon and text

Tags: android, material-design, materialbutton

As the topic said, with materialButton, I want to set up the distance between drawableLeft icon and text, I do not want to use icon, just drawableLeft

By default, the drawableleft icon is far away from text, I want to make them closer, but I cannot use icon and icon gravity. If I use icon and icon gravity, it will not show because of the style I use, but if I change the style, then there will be another problem: there will be shadow below the button. I do not want the shadow, so I have to use the style.

What I want is a MaterialButton, grey background, left icon, centre is text, icon and text is closed, MaterialButton is round corner, no shadow below the MaterialButton. Here is the code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"              
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/btnShortCut"
style="@style/Button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="36dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
app:backgroundTint="@color/background"
app:cornerRadius="@dimen/cornerM"
app:strokeColor="@color/primaryGrey"
app:strokeWidth="0.5dp"
android:padding="5dp"
android:textColor="@color/secondaryText"
android:textSize="@dimen/fontBody" >

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>

<style name="Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You can use `android:layout_marginLeft` to push the drawableLeft closer to the text and to keep some space between the drawable and the text (in case of using center gravity for example) you can use `android:drawablePadding`, test it and let me know

Comment: To remove the shadow from the button, add this to it `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"`

Comment: You can use app:iconPadding

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary for you to use a material button? Have you considered using a FrameLayout with a textview overlapped on it?

In your example it would look something like this, but with some edits since I'm not sure exactly how you want it to look.

```
<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/btnShortCut"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="36dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
  android:orientation="vertical"                                                                
  android:gravity="center"
  app:cornerRadius="@dimen/cornerM"
  app:strokeColor="@color/primaryGrey"
  app:strokeWidth="0.5dp"
  android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
      android:drawableStart="@drawable/<your icon here>"
      android:drawablePadding="15dp"
      android:textColor="@color/secondaryText"
      android:textSize="@dimen/fontBody"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thank you, but no, I need to use material button, since company ask me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

**Just Add This**

```
app:iconGravity="textStart"
```